# Swift file reading permission error on macOS sandbox

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, appstore-sandbox

I'm trying to read the contents of a file on the filesystem in a macOS Swift app (Xcode 9 / Swift 4).

I'm using the following snippet for it:

```
let path = "/my/path/string.txt"
let s = try! String(contentsOfFile: path)
print(s)
```

My problem is the following:

1. This works in a **Playground**
2. This works when I use the **Command Line Tool** macOS app template
3. This terminates in a permission error when I use the **Cocoa App** macOS app template

The permission error is the following:

> Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error:
>
> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file "data.txt" couldn't be opened because you don't have permission to view it."
>
> UserInfo={NSFilePath=/my/path/data.txt, NSUnderlyingError=0x60c0000449b0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}

I guess it's related to sandboxing but I found no information about it.

1. How can I read from the filesystem in a sandboxed app? I mean there are so many GUI apps which need an Open File dialog, it cannot be a realistic restriction of sandboxed apps to not read files from outside the sandbox.
2. Alternatively, how can I switch off sandboxing in Build Settings?
3. Finally, I tried to compare the `project.pbxproj` files between the default Cocoa Apps and Command Line Tool template and I didn't see any meaningful difference, like something about security or sandbox. If not here, where are those settings stored?

Comment: You are sandboxing your app without knowing why you need to do it.  Otherwise, you wouldn't have a line like let path = "/my/path/string.txt".

Comment: I do not want to sandbox my app, I just want to read a file from the file system in a Cocoa App template based app.

Comment: If you do not want to sandbox your app, then why do you ask "How can I read from the filesystem in a sandboxed app?"?

Comment: I don't want sandbox, but would still like to understand how a sandboxed app should solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bullet 1: you have the answer, you need to use `NSOpenPanel` to obtain the user's permission to access the file. You can use `NSOpenPanel` methods to restrict the user's choice to the cancel button and just the file you wish - thus making a "request access to" dialog. Start with [Apple's App Sandbox Design Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html).

Your bullet 2: you've the right idea, just the wrong tab, you should find the sandboxing switch on the Summary tab.

HTH