# Access data secured by macOS User Data Protections

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I’m trying to access the `~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist` file from within a CLI application I’m writing. The problem is that macOS 10.14 (Mojave) is stopping me from accessing the `~/Library/Safari` directory at all.

According to the WWDC ’18 session “[Your Apps and the Future of macOS Security](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/702/)”, this is to ensure user data security, which seems sensible. Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to request access to this directory.

The slides from the linked talk mention that the user is prompted automatically when accessing directories in question, but that doesn’t seem to be the case. All I keep receiving is the following error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “Bookmarks.plist” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/kilian/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist, NSUnderlyingError=0x101602470 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}

Interestingly enough, I can add my terminal application to *System Settings > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Application Data*, and am then able to access the directory, but this feels like a very awkward workaround.

Is there any way to request authorization to access the directory and the file directly? Is this possibly limited to `NSApplication`s and not possible for a simple binary just lying around?

Comment: I would look into using a OpenFile dialog, if you can somehow get one triggered from the console; then provide the path to the OpenFile dialog and have the user confirm they want to open that path; which will give access to that path to your app's sandbox.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493813/swift-file-reading-permission-error-on-macos-sandbox

Comment: I'm not sure this is a duplicate of the linked question. I don't have a sandboxed cocoa app, but I'm trying to access data the system protects starting with 10.14. I'm also not sure if using an open file dialog from a CLI is possible, but I will experiment 

Comment: @KilianKoeltzsch The only thing browser-related I saw in the sessions is Browsing History. Are bookmarks browsing history?

Comment: @Purpose Those are persisted in ~/Library/Safari/History.db as far as I can tell, but it seems the entire directory is protected.

Comment: @KilianKoeltzsch If it were so that the whole directory has the same protection as history, then you have to add the app to the System-App list, since the session said you can‘t request permission for it. Have you tried OpenFile?

Comment: I just tried using an `NSOpenPanel`, which actually displays a small red no entry sign on the Safari directory and won't allow me to see files from within, so apparently it's started with the same permissions as my program.

Comment: @KilianKoeltzsch Have you made yiur app a System-App as the session suggested? Maybe it removes the x? If not, then its likely not related to the new protections.